# Javascript/AJAX script to check if PHP page outputs 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to create an instant messaging site. Every ten seconds I want a javascript/ajax script to check if there are new messages. I thought that I could have a php page output 1 if there are. I have done the php coding, but can not get the javascript side to work. I have tried using $.get and am having a bit of trouble. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my ajax code:

```
var check;
function checkForMessages() {
    $.get("/checkmsg.php", function(data) {
        if(data == 1) {
            alert("There is a new message");
        }
    });
}

check = setInterval(checkForMessages, 10000);
```

My php code always outputs 1 for testing purposes

Comment: What code do you have already?  Post the PHP code and your attemps at the js code

Comment: Okay there is the javascript code

Comment: get firebug or use the debuggger in chrome; look at the ajax/xhr responses and see what it's telling you. it won't return 1 for instance...I think it's a string, possibly something different depending on what you set for [dataType](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/).

Comment: Are you sure the url is correct?

Comment: try to use developer tools and firebug first to check if there are errors

Comment: done that too, used chrome dev tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing at the end of your php code you have this:

```
echo '1';
```

For your JS i suggest $.post():

```
jQuery.post( '/checkmsg.php', function(data) { 
    if (data.search('1') !== -1) {
        alert("There is a new message");
    } else {
        alert("Something went wrong.");
    }
});
```

Comment: That doesn't work either :( - doesn't output anything even though the page outputs 1

Comment: @ethanh - wut browser r u using, and does it `echo "1"` or `echo 1`

Comment: Also your code gives me `TypeError: Object bound: function () { return document.getElementById.apply(document, arguments) } has no method 'post'` in the Chrome javascript console

Comment: @ethanh - Do you have jquery set up?

Comment: @ethanh - You need to include it in the page, I updated the script, try it now.

Comment: Where might I get the jQuery to include?

Comment: @ethanh - In the head of the document: `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @ethanh - You need to use two different script elements, one with the src, and one with the code

Comment: hasn't `type="text/javascript"` been taken out in html5?

Comment: @ethanh No, language has been taken out

Comment: When I add `document.write("test");` it doesn't output, though javascript is enabled.

Comment: @ethanh You must have a JS problem, try using a different browser

Comment: No problem man, Ur welcome, jst select my answer as true and one up it